# Comments editor - Preview and code formatting when writing a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments

As we use **Ask Question** *(thanks to its powerful editor however)* when writing an answer or the question, I'd like to use this place **for asking to request this feature for comments writing** on the desktop browsers, such as Chrome, etc.

I have already seen such feature for ***iOS*** (*and maybe Android*) where we can use **format** (*when pressing on the text*) to format code, etc. on the Stack Exchange mobile app.

But, what about simplifying and making peoples' work easier than before by adding a code format editor like using JavaScript when the user types the comment and it opens a simple and useful code formatting for that?

Something like the following image for when the user types the comment:

[image]

It may sound somewhat useless, but by adding such a thing, **I didn’t mean to add the whole thing in comments section**. However, I’d like to know about **at least adding a preview of what we write in there**. At least a preview!

Comment: I think asking for the editor got you the downvotes. Consider making a question to ask only for the preview. I'd appreciate that to get the magic links (e.g. `[mcve]`) right. I usually have to edit after getting them wrong... And those links match the purpose of comments very well. So I'd upvote a request for only the preview.

Comment: Yes and that’s interesting why people downvoting the question..I didn’t however meant only editor, i meant preview and making text bold and maybe more.

Comment: Read the answers, many people will think alike (e.g. I do) and downvote to indicate that the proposed feature is not needed (though I did not), probably only very few or none (in this case) downvoted the question as badly asked. That is how voting on meta works.

Comment: I want a live preview for comments, I don't want the buttons for formatting though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Comments are not important enough to warrant an editor, and is best not to encourage users to add additional format to those they post. The more work users invest in comments, the more they'll complain when comments get deleted. And comments are deleted *all the time*.

Besides, only **bold**, *italic*, `code`, and [links](http://www.example.com) are supported in comments (that I know of), with no newlines rendered; and it is usually faster to just type the additional characters than using a GUI (with the arguable exception of links, I guess).

Your example of opening an editor to write code in comments seems particularly unenlightened. If you need to add more than a couple of code keywords in a comment, you are probably doing it wrong, IMO.

Comment: No I didn’t mean adding a couple of code in comment. However, if it’s not important, why do we have it here?! Seems useless *in your side*. Seems **useful especially, in Android tag** to me by the way.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท I didn't say "useless". I said "not important enough". I reckon that the usefulness of adding code keywords is more or less the same in most tags. And since code you write will be unformatted in comments (no newlines, no mantaining spaces, etc), I insist than adding a couple of backticks is faster anyway.

Comment: Well yeah. I meant using backticks but with a helpful editor for that or even a preview! than adding couple of codes in there. Of course, can’t use multiple lines of codes in there however, it can be improved (in my thoughts) Anyways, Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I would agree with this answer but perhaps a tamper monkey script or plugins for a browser that could be an option so when a comments box is active on a stack exchange system it shows a hints box with the formatting syntax like the how to format on Ask a Question when the body is focused.

Comment: @Martin, by the time you are allowed to comment you must have earned 50 rep, so in theory you should be already familiar with couple characters to enable formatting in a comment. And installing a userscript to remind the user of this seems like a serious overkill to me. A userscript to have live preview wouldn't be necessary _wrong_... but personally I believe than the 5' minute grace period for edits is more than enough.

Comment: @yiviI would agree but if it's a user script that a user chooses to install the overhead is on them :D they could not be bothered to learn and to then choose to install something so they don't have to learn it's their choice, it was a possible option if someone really wants it.

Comment: @Martin I meant the overhead of _writing it_. If you feel so inclined, be my guest. :) Personally, I feel it is not a worthy endeveaour, for the reasons I offered earlier.

Comment: @Yivi well [here is the JS](https://pastebin.com/6Yp7wFK1) is someone if someone wants to wrap it for Tamper monkey or build a browser plugin whatever they wanna do with it :D

Answer (score 4):

I think the limited formatting options are enough for the role Comments play here.

When the comment thread is too long, it already takes the attention from Questions and Answers. If it were to have extra (and more complex) editing styles, it would be extra content competing for the real state area from Q&A's.

Some Stack Exchange sites strictly enforce the instructions of the comment box and moderators wipe entire comment threads -moving them to chat- without any mercy:

> *Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information.*